# TypeError at /register/ list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can i solve this issue in my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import EmailInput, FileInput, PasswordInput, TextInput, Textarea
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
class RegistertionForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'validate form-control', 'placeholder': 'Full Name', 'type': 'text', 'id': 'first_name'}), min_length=2, max_length=150)
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username', 'type': 'text',  'id': 'username'}), min_length=4, max_length=150)
    email = forms.CharField(widget=EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'type': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Enter your email address', 'id': 'email'}))
    number = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'type': 'number', 'placeholder': 'phone number', 'id': 'number'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password', 'id': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Confirm-password', 'id': 'password2'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control',  'placeholder': 'Write about yourself', 'id': 'description'}))
    # picture = forms.CharField(widget=FileInput(attrs={'class': 'validate form-control', 'type': 'file', 'id': 'profile', 'name': 'profile'}))



def clean_firstname(self):
    firstname = self.cleaned_data['firstname'].lower()
    qs = User.objects.filter(firstname=firstname)
    if qs.count():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Name already exists")
    return  firstname

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
    qp = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    if qp.count():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exist")
    return username


def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
    r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
    if r.count():
        raise  forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
    return email

def clean_phone(self):
    number = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
    r = User.objects.filter(number=number)
    if r.count():
        raise  forms.ValidationError("Phone number already exists")
    return number

def clean_password2(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password and password2 and password != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password don't match")

    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
        first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
        number=self.cleaned_data['number'],
        email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
        password=self.cleaned_data['password'],
        description=self.changed_data['description'],
    )
    return user
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.